# convert js array to php array and check its content

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I want to sent a JS array to remote php server and convert it to a php array.
To check if php array is equal to js array I'm trying to get its members inside `result` div, but without success.

```
var rlist = ["title1", "title2", "title3"];
var b = JSON.stringify(rlist);
$.ajax({
        url: 'reorder.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'b': b},
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
        });
```

reorder.php

```
$rlist = json_decode( $_POST['b'], true );
echo $rlist;
```

Comment: That should work, except that you cannot `echo` an array like that. Try a `var_dump()` to see the actual contents.

Comment: use `echo "<pre>"; print_r(json_decode($_POST['b'], true));` in reorder.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put this code in the *reorder.php*

```
$rlist = json_decode( $_POST['b'], true );
foreach ($rlist as $value) {
    echo "<div>" . $value . "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_decode as `jQuery ajax` submits it's arrays as json.

```
// Use as object
$json = json_decode($_POST['postdata']);

// Use as
echo $json->seomthign

$json = $_POST['postdata'];

// Output array
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(json_decode($json));
echo "</pre>";
```